# Regarding or operator in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hey guys my OR is not working in elsif ..... then statement

....

```
   create or replace PROCEDURE UPD_CUST_STATUS_IN_DB(pcustid Number, pstatus Varchar2) As
   vCustid Number;
   NO_ROWS_UPDATED EXCEPTION;
   INVALID_STATUS EXCEPTION;
   BEGIN
       SELECT CUSTID INTO vCustid FROM CUSTOMER
       WHERE CUSTID = pcustid;
  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
       RAISE NO_ROWS_UPDATED;
  ELSIF PSTATUS != 'OK' OR PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND'  THEN
      RAISE INVALID_STATUS;
  ELSE
      UPDATE CUSTOMER
      SET STATUS = PSTATUS
      WHERE CUSTID = PCUSTID;
   END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_ROWS_UPDATED THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20127, 'Error: Customer ID not found');
  WHEN INVALID_STATUS THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20132, 'Error: Invalid Status value');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);
  END;
```

....

Thanks for help in advance. :)

Comment: By "not working" I guess you mean it is always raising INVALID_STATUS?

Comment: it means the second condition which says != 'SUSPEND' is not working

Comment: There are multiple ways to examine this. You can also try as `ELSIF (PSTATUS != 'OK' OR PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND')`. Also, try 

`ELSIF PSTATUS NOT IN ('OK', 'SUSPEND')`. Since it is case-sensitive, its a good idea to double-check the case and the spellings (directly copy the value as stored in the table). 
Another  option would be to try a simple SQL statement with `WHERE` clause as `PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND'`.
If possible, share a small section of the table with these values.

Comment: But what does it mean "not working". What your code is supposed to do and what it does instead?

Comment: frankly speaking i am new to pl/sql and whenever i use and /or the second condition always not work, i took care of and somehow but here everything is working properly its just when i add an entry with SUSPEND status this code does not take it in.

Comment: @DiljotSingh, when you write a simple `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE STATUS = 'SUSPEND'`, do you see any result? Similarly, write it as `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE STATUS != 'SUSPEND'` and then add `OR/AND STATUS !='OK'`. That is how you can identify it yourself. Unless we see the table with the relevant data, can't help much.

Comment: thanks guys,  solution @william robertson mentioned worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code:

A `select into` that finds no rows will raise a `no_data_found` exception. As you don't define one of those, it'll go to the `others` exception, which doesn't do anything useful - I'd remove it.

Assuming the `select into` does find a row in `customer`, then you'll be here:

```
ELSIF PSTATUS != 'OK' OR PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND' THEN
    RAISE INVALID_STATUS;
```

Whatever the value of `pstatus`, that condition will be true so it will raise the exception.

Say the value is `'OK'`. It's not equal to `'SUSPEND'`, so raise the exception. Or say the value is `'SUSPEND'`: now it's not equal to `'OK'` so it's the exception handler for you.

The only way to pass that check is if `pstatus` is null, as then it's neither equal nor not equal to anything, in which case it would go ahead and set customer status to null.

Maybe need something like:

```
if pstatus in ('OK', 'SUSPEND') then
    update customer
    set    status = pstatus
    where  custid = pcustid;
else
    raise invalid_status;
end if;
```

Comment: A quibble, but if `pstatus` is `NULL`, then both inequality statements will evaluate to false and the condition will be false.

Comment: Good point. The only value of `status` that could pass the `invalid_status` validation would be null.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the OR by AND. The OR predicate is working properly, it is just the wrong predicate. Assuming status is declared as not null, the problem you have is that as written it MUST ALWAYS return True and thus ALWAYS raise INVALID_STATUS. Consider that an OR returns true if any of the specified sub-conditions is true. Now consider your statement:

```
PSTATUS != 'OK' OR PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND'
```

Assume PSTATUS is equal to OK. Then the 1st sub-condition (PSTATUS != 'OK') is False, but the second sub-condition (PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND') is necessary True. So now your condition has been reduced to

```
False OR True
```

The same analysis can be applied when PSTSTUS is equal to SUSPEND. For any other value of PSTATUS both sides evaluate to True so the overall condition is True. This condition can must always evaluate to True and therefore the INVALID_STATUS exception is raised.  
So now eventuate consider the AND predicate. Recall it returns True only when all sub-conditions return true. So again consider the PSTATUS value OK. The sub-conditions again return False and True respectively which returns False overall. Then PSTATUS value 'SUSPEND' The sub-conditions return True and False respectively which again returns False overall. The INVALID_STATUS exception is not raised.  But any other value (say ABC) then both sub-conditions return True and the overall condition thus returns True and the INVALID_STATUS exception is raised.
Conclusion: Change "ELSIF PSTATUS != 'OK' OR PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND'" to

```
ELSIF PSTATUS != 'OK' AND PSTATUS != 'SUSPEND' THEN
```